# How do you create Mystery Seeds when they need Mystery Seeds?

Tags: atelier-rorona-plus

I have the recipe for Mystery Seeds but the recipe is:

- Mystery Seed x1
- (Elixir) x1

Now I've already used up the Mystery Seed I first got and I'm on the last assignment of the second year (Assignment 8 - Make Barrels and Canons) and I've not gotten any more, I haven't seen any in any of the shops including Cole's

So How do you created Mystery Seeds when they need Mystery Seeds?

Comment: Huh, that's delightfully recursive. Do you get more than one mystery seed out of the recipe at least?

Comment: @Ash If I know anything about Atelier games, it doesn't.  The recipe is probably for changing the item traits for use in other items it's used in.

Answer (score 1):

[According to GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/726469-atelier-rorona-plus-the-alchemist-of-arland/71330898),  you can get Mystery Seeds by going to [Orthogalaxen](https://atelier.wikia.com/wiki/Orthogalaxen) and opening question marks on the floors until you find one?